# Using Image insert control in code

Tags: wp-admin, images, uploads

I am adding additional pages to wordpress backend and I would like to use the built-in image uploader and browser. I couldn't find any examples on how to add it to my form.

Assuming that I have a text input or something similiar - what do I have to do to allow users pick a previously uploaded image so that the image link would show up in the textfield?

edit:

I've created an iframe that's loading media-uploader.php but now I have no idea how to get the picked image to go to my textfield.

Answer (score 2):

The [Image Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-widget/) plugin uses the media uploader. You may want to look at its code source. It is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar (inserting external images into posts from a specific source) and I couldn't find any appropriate hooks or functions to use, so I ended up copying the relevant code from `wp-admin/includes/media.php` and `wp-admin/media-upload.php` into my plugin in order to use the functionality.

Comment: could you please post the plugin that you created and the admin metabox code you added to your custom post type? Thanks so much in advance

Comment: @NetConstructor.com It's not completed, but I will update here when it is finished.

Comment: did you finish this by chance?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused. Do you mean that you want the end user to be able to use the image picker from the back end, and have access to all the pictures from other sections?

If so, I'm pretty sure it already does that, by default.

Comment: I want to know how to use the image picker in my code. I couldn't find that.